# PHP num_rows and fetch_assoc in the same statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Below is the code that i am having trouble with:

```
$stmt->store_result();
if($stmt->num_rows<1) return false;
$res2=$stmt->get_result();
if($GLOBAL_DB->error) die($GLOBAL_DB->error);
while($res=$res2->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) $result[]=$res['Field'];
```

I get the following error when i run the code: `Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now`. Everything before this code works 100% because it has been tested. The thing is, this code worked before, but then i wanted to check on the `num_rows` as well as fetching.
The following code works fine:

```
$res2=$stmt->get_result();
if($GLOBAL_DB->error) die($GLOBAL_DB->error);
while($res=$res2->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) $result[]=$res['Field'];
```

#### This is the error i'm getting

`Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now`

Comment: `return false;` Is the first code in a function/method???? If so show it as such

Comment: There's no need to use `$stmt->store_result();`. After `$res2=$stmt->get_result();`, you can directly use `$res2->num_rows` to get the number of rows.

Comment: Removed `store_result();` and it worked. I swear i tried to do that before and it kept showing an error. Anyways, THANKS! Could you throw an answer?

Comment: Wait, nvm. it didn't actually work